# Passing an object with Aurelia router.navigate to a view

Tags: aurelia

I need to do a master-details view when I click on a row. I have the [code in a branch](https://github.com/logankd/JQueryToAurelia/blob/aureliaTSCore/src/aurelia/EnergyAureliaWeb/src/energy/energyRowViewModel.ts) [here's the commit link](https://github.com/logankd/JQueryToAurelia/commit/7aa8a59ff6c58587af0a249241048c691471958a).

```
  let urlDetail = this.router.generate('energy-details', {model: this.model});
  this.router.navigate(urlDetail);
```

This works, but the query string is awful. How do I send the model across in memory?

This was really hard to find an example for. https://github.com/softchris/aurelia was the best one.
Is there a better way to do master-detail views? I'm new to Aurelia.

http://localhost:5000/#/energy-details?model%5BdataSeriesId%5D=ES&model%5BcountryId%5D=392&model%5BcountryName%5D=Japan&model%5BtransactionCode%5D=01&model%5BcommodityTransactionId%5D=ES01&model%5BcommodityTransactionName%5D=Electricity%20-%20solar%20production%2C%20public&model%5Byear%5D=2000&model%5Bunit%5D=Kilowatt-hours%2C%20million&model%5Bquantity%5D=2&model%5BfootnoteSequenceId%5D=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reconsider if you just don't want to use id. Quite often in a mater-details you need to make a new query to get more data anyway.

If not possible for your use case, maybe it makes sense to have a DataManager singleton.

- Create a DataManager class that you inject in your List and Detail ViewModel. By default every injected class is a singleton in aurelia
- In the list ViewModel, make sure your data is saved in the DataManager
- Routing by passing the id only
- In the details ViewModel call your method getModelById(id) of the DataManger

Comment: Thank you for the "Reconsider if you just don't want to use id.". I was thinking something was built in, but the Singleton is another good idea.

Comment: Ahahah sorry about that. Yes I also often want to pass the data to make a quick preview of the details before loading the full data. But storing data into a route can make things heavy to serialize for handling page history.